# Deskewing scanned image to match original image using OpenCV and SIFT/SURF

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an original page in digital form and several scanned versions of the same page. My goal is to deskew the scanned pages such that they match the original page as much as possible. I know that I could use the Probabilistic Hough Transform as described [here](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/) for fixing the rotation but the scanned papers also differ in size as some people scaled the page to a different paper format. I think that the findHomography() function in OpenCV in combination with the keypoints from SIFT/SURF are exactly what I need to solve this problem. However, I just can't get my deskew() function to work.

Most of my code stems from the following two sources: 
http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/ and http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# FIXME: doesn't work
def deskew():
    im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, M, (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))
    plt.imshow(im_out, 'gray')
    plt.show()


# resizing images to improve speed
factor = 0.4
img1 = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("image.png", 0), None, fx=factor, fy=factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
img2 = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("imageSkewed.png", 0), None, fx=factor, fy=factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h, w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)

    deskew()

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
else:
    print("Not  enough  matches are found   -   %d/%d" % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

# show matching keypoints
draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),  # draw  matches in  green   color
                   singlePointColor=None,
                   matchesMask=matchesMask,  # draw only    inliers
                   flags=2)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: Original Image] [image: Skewed Image]

Comment: I did something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435488/align-x-ray-images-find-rotation-rotate-and-crop/32441230#32441230) which might be of help.

Comment: @MartinEvans Thanks, that's similar but what I need is to align the skewed image as closely as possible to the original image. I just found this [Mathlab tutorial](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) that exactly solves my problem but unfortunately I don't get step 5. Do you know how to adapt my example code to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I was very close to solving my own problem.
Here's the working version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math


def deskew():
    im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(skewed_image, np.linalg.inv(M), (orig_image.shape[1], orig_image.shape[0]))
    plt.imshow(im_out, 'gray')
    plt.show()

orig_image = cv2.imread(r'image.png', 0)
skewed_image = cv2.imread(r'imageSkewed.png', 0)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(orig_image, None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(skewed_image, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

    # see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html for details
    ss = M[0, 1]
    sc = M[0, 0]
    scaleRecovered = math.sqrt(ss * ss + sc * sc)
    thetaRecovered = math.atan2(ss, sc) * 180 / math.pi
    print("Calculated scale difference: %.2f\nCalculated rotation difference: %.2f" % (scaleRecovered, thetaRecovered))

    deskew()

else:
    print("Not  enough  matches are found   -   %d/%d" % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that works with OpenCV 2.4.x. Answer above uses OpenCV 3.x:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import errno
from os import path

SRC_FOLDER = "images/source/{YOUR_SOURCE_IMAGE_DIR}"
OUT_FOLDER = "images/output"
DETECTOR = cv2.SURF()

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
MATCHER = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10


def deskew(base_image_shape, skewed_image, homography):
    return cv2.warpPerspective(skewed_image, np.linalg.inv(homography), (base_image_shape[1], base_image_shape[0]))


def compute_points_and_descriptors(image):
    """
    :param image: numpy.ndarray
    :return: keypoints, descriptors
    """
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    eq_hist_gray_image = cv2.equalizeHist(gray_image)
    return DETECTOR.detectAndCompute(eq_hist_gray_image, None)


def find_homography(base_keypoints, base_descriptors, skewed_image):
    skewed_keypoints, skewed_descriptors = compute_points_and_descriptors(skewed_image)
    matches = MATCHER.knnMatch(base_descriptors, skewed_descriptors, k=2)
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    # print(len(good))
    if len(good) < MIN_MATCH_COUNT: return None

    base_pts = np.float32([base_keypoints[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    skewed_pts = np.float32([skewed_keypoints[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    homography, _ = cv2.findHomography(base_pts, skewed_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    return homography


if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_contents = os.walk(SRC_FOLDER)
    dirpath, _, fnames = src_contents.next()

    image_dir = os.path.split(dirpath)[-1]
    output_dir = os.path.join(OUT_FOLDER, image_dir)

    try:
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

    print "Processing '" + image_dir + "' folder..."

    image_files = sorted([os.path.join(dirpath, name) for name in fnames])
    img_stack = [cv2.imread(name) for name in image_files]

    base_image = img_stack[0]
    base_image_shape = base_image.shape
    base_keypoints, base_descriptors = compute_points_and_descriptors(base_image)
    cv2.imwrite(path.join(output_dir, "output0.png"), base_image)
    for ix, image in enumerate(img_stack[1:]):
        homography = find_homography(base_keypoints, base_descriptors, image)
        deskewed_image = deskew(base_image_shape, image, homography)
        cv2.imwrite(path.join(output_dir, "output{}.png".format(ix+1)), deskewed_image)

    print("Done")
```